# jquery selectors and disabled='disabled'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just noticed that a disabled input text field is not picked up in a selector when it is disabled. Is there a way to say select inputs disabled or not...

```
<input type="text" name="MYNAME" id="preXXXX" disabled='disabled' value="my Value"  />

$.each($('input[id^="pre"], select[id^="pre"]').serializeArray(), function() {
```

Comment: but I can select disabled inputs check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gPJLU/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A disabled input field [**is**](http://jsfiddle.net/puYvm/) picked up in a selector, however it is **not** included when the form is serialized (`serializeArray()`), as it is not a ["successful control"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). This behaviour is documented in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray).

Comment: @mustapha: Give the `readonly` attribute that @zzzzBov mentioned a go. Alternately, you could reenable the disabled input *just* *before* you call `serializeArray()`

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html) specifies that [disabled form fields should **not** be submitted with the form](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-form-data-set) (3.1 bullet #2).

jQuery does it's best to follow the spec as far as expected results.

If you *want* data to be transmitted with a form, but you want to prevent a user from editing the value, you should use [`readonly="readonly"`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-readonly-attribute) instead of `disabled="disabled"`. Read only fields are just that, the user can read them, but not edit them.

As far as selection goes, you just need to use the jQuery factory method for selection:

```
$('input[id^="pre"], select[id^="pre"]')
```

And you can iterate over every element using the `each` function:

```
$('input[id^="pre"], select[id^="pre"]').each( function( index, element ){
  ...do stuff...
});
```

Comment: I try to urge everyone to read the HTML5 spec, it's very well written, and not too hard to understand. There are a *lot* of important details that many developers have no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

If at all you want to submit the disabled input fields you can try something like this

```
//This gives an array of name/value pair object.
var inputArray = $('input[id^="pre"], select[id^="pre"]').serializeArray();

//Now look only for disabled input fields and push into inputArray and then process that.
$("input:disabled").each(function(){
   inputArray.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
});

//Now process inputArray which contains all the input fields name/value pair
$.each(inputArray, function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You can use `each` like this:

```
$('input[id^="pre"], select[id^="pre"]').each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: won't I lose the functionality of serialize?